# How often does Tor send a heartbeat in a circuit?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I just wonder how often will Tor send a packet when the circuit is idle (when you launch Tor and do not visit any website)? I think Tor will regularly send a cell to keep the circuit alive.

I did not find any solid number in Tor's manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've modified the `KeepalivePeriod` in your `torrc`, it should be using the default value, which is 300 seconds (5 minutes) according to [the documentation](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

Comment: I think you are right! Thanks!